# Build JObject from JSONPath

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm a bit new to using the Newtonsoft JSON library for .NET. Is there any way to create a JObject or JToken from a JSONPath?

So for example something like the following.

```
string jsonPath = "$.ArrayA[0].ArrayB[0].Property";
JObject jObj = JObject.FromJSONPath(jsonPath); // SOMETHING LIKE THIS
```

The result would be a JObject or JToken that looks like this.

```
{
    "ArrayA": [{
        "ArrayB": [{
            "Property": ""
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

If you have some existing JSON, you can parse it to a JToken and then *select* one or more descendant JTokens from it using [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) or [`SelectTokens`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  For example:

```
string json = @"{ ""ArrayA"": [{ ""ArrayB"": [{ ""Property"": ""foo"" }] }] }";
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
JToken fooToken = token.SelectToken("$..Property");
Console.WriteLine(fooToken.ToString());    // prints "foo"
```

You can also manually build a nested structure of JTokens.  For example, you can create the JObject in your question like this:

```
var obj = new JObject(new JProperty("ArrayA", new JArray(
             new JObject(new JProperty("ArrayB", new JArray(
                new JObject(new JProperty("Property", ""))))))));
```

However, there is no built-in way to create a JToken from nothing but a JsonPath expression.  You would need to roll your own method to do something like that.  But keep in mind that JsonPath was designed as a query mechanism; it doesn't map cleanly to creation of new objects.  Here are some issues you would need to think about:

- In your example expression, `$.ArrayA[0].ArrayB[0].Property`, what type is `Property`?  Is it string, number, boolean, object or an empty array?  How would you specify that?
- How would you specify creation of an object with multiple properties?
- What would an expression like `$..book[(@.length-1)]` create?