# How to override values in JObject

Tags: c#, json, .net, loops, asp.net-core

I keep trying to override values inside my JObject (i'm reciving it from web appliaction, so it can be different). I tried to use for loop, but i don't know how to iterate with JObject. Foreach is useless because i can't edit values inside my JObject.

This is my attempt:

```
public JObject TranslateJson(string jsonString, LanguageCharset languageCharset)
    {
      JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
      for ( int i = 0; i > json.Count; i++)
      {
        json[i].Value = "test"; //Compiler Error CS1656
      }
      return json;
    }
```

#Update1

```
public JObject TranslateJson(string jsonString, LanguageCharset languageCharset)
    {
      JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
      foreach (var x in json)
      {
        json[x.Key] = "test";
      }
      return json;
    }
```

#Update2

Part of json:

```
{
  "common": {
    "appName": "[App name] Web",
    "other": "other",
    "others": "others",
    "dateRange": {
      "start": "Date from",
      "end": "Date to"
    },
    "sidebar": {
      "dashboard": "[App name] dashboard",
      "violations": {
        "list": "Infringement list",
        "timeline": "Activities and infringements"
      },
      "drivers": "Driver list",
      "profile": "Profile",
      "settings": "Settings",
      "logout": "Sign out"
    },
    "tariff": {
      "name": {
        "CZ": "Czech tariff",
        "RO": "Romanian tariff",
        "DE": "German tariff",
        "GB": "British tariff",
        "LT": "Lithuanian tariff",
        "DK": "Danish tariff",
        "PL": "Polish tariff",
        "BE": "Belgian tariff",
        "CH": "Swiss tariff",
        "FR": "French tariff",
        "LU": "Luxembourgish tariff",
        "SE": "Swedish tariff",
        "HU": "Magyar tariff"
           [..] (more nestings)
```

#Update 3

Example input json:

```
{
  "weapons": 
  {
    "axe": "axe",
    "sword": "sword" },
  "tools":
  {
    "saw": "saw"
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
{
  "weapons": 
  {
    "axe": "translated",
    "sword": "translated" },
  "tools":
  {
    "saw": "translated"
  }
}
```

Why only transladed? Because when i can to overwrite value inside any nest of that json structure, i just can call my transtalion function.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you Add or Update a JProperty Value in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085926/how-do-you-add-or-update-a-jproperty-value-in-a-jobject)

Comment: Not at all, check my update:.

Comment: Im puzzle by that comment. Either the doc is wrong and there is no reproduction to your error. as you can see in this demo https://dotnetfiddle.net/2zl09h. Or we are missing a [mre]

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail, and give the object you need to replace, you can provide your `json`

Comment: Your missunderstanding might come from Object != JObject. You may want to parse to `JToken` and check `if (token is JArray)` or `if (token is JObject)` and have a recusive call in case of array. But that pure speculation based on my cristal ball please follow ask [ask], and [mre] by providing an Example input and expected output

Comment: I will also check the The type of the current token you are updating in order to not errase other type:  `"{ 'arr1':[1,2,3] }"` => `"{ 'arr1':'test' }"`

Comment: @DragandDrop I just want to translate all values inside json from english language to my origin language by using my database, so the point to do womething like in Update3

Answer (score 0):

Below is a demo,you can check it.

```
var jsonString = @"
                    { items: [
                    {
                      ""name"": ""1111"", 
                      ""name2"": ""value2"", 
                      ""type"":  ""2222""
                    },
                    {
                      ""name"": ""33333"",
                      ""name2"": ""value2"",
                      ""type"": ""444444""
                    }
                    ] }";
       
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
       
        foreach (JObject o in json["items"].AsEnumerable())
        {
           foreach (var x in o)
            {    
               o[x.Key] = "test";        
            } 
        }
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: It's close, but not whats i wanted. Because 1st: i don't knwo how first node will be called (it can be items, languages or other things). 2nd, it can have multiply nodes, file for test have 11 nested nodes so i need to do it in different way. I will post json file to translate

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that:

```
public string TranslateJson(string jsonString, LanguageCharset languageCharset)
    {
      JToken json = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
      foreach (var element in json)
      {
        if (element is JObject)
        {
          return "object";
        } else if (element is JArray)
        {
          return "array";
        }
      }
      return "you fckd up";
    }
```

And it always returning "you fckd up", but i want to get something different than it, but idk how to achive it

Comment: It happens because element is always a "Property".

Comment: Yes, element of a Token are Property. but Property.Value should be the JToken.

Comment: @DragandDrop Then when i try to do if (element.Value is JToken) then in this line i got error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0837?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0837)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322438/getting-all-the-properties-with-a-name-from-a-json-and-changing-the-value may help.  To get the type you can also use type property and compare to jtoken type enum.